# I am confused with SQL command differences

Tags: plsql

Why would you use `insert into dept values didbuild;` instead of `insert into dept values did_insrt` in the following code?:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

declare

did_insrt dept%rowtype;

Begin

did_insrt.did := 4;

did_insrt.dname := 'accounting';

insert into dept values didbuild;

end;


Select * from dept;
```

Comment: are you sure this is running?

Answer (score 0):

It should be did_insrt.

If record variable is created using the %ROWTYPE command then we would be able to insert record directly into the table.

```
declare

did_insrt dept%rowtype;

Begin

did_insrt.did := 4;

did_insrt.dname := 'accounting';

insert into dept values did_insrt;

commit;

end;
```